# Go - ReverseProxy to Apache proxy error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: go, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

i have some troubles with my own ReverseProxy i've written in Go. I want to connect my Golang-Webserver with my Apache Webserver. My Apache Webserver should be running on https and the Reverse-Proxy too. So i've written following code, but I always get the error: proxy error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
So must the apache uses the same certificate as the apache or what is the problem? Here some code snippets but I think its a problem with the certificates without ssl everything works fine :(

```
func (p *Proxy) directorApache(req *http.Request) {
    mainServer := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", Config.HostMain, Config.PortMain)
    req.URL.Scheme = "https"
    req.URL.Host = mainServer
}
func (p *Proxy) directorGo(req *http.Request) {
    goServer := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", Config.GoHost, Config.GoPort)
    req.URL.Scheme = "http"
    req.URL.Host = goServer
}


func (p *Proxy) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(req.URL.Path)
    if p.isGoRequest(req) {
        fmt.Println("GO")
        p.goProxy.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
        return
    }
    p.httpProxy.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
}
func main() {

    var configPath = flag.String("conf", "./configReverse.json", "Path to the Json config file.")

    flag.Parse()
    proxy := New(*configPath)

    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(Config.PathCert, Config.PathPrivateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("server: loadkeys: %s", err)
    }
    config := tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true, Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp",
    net.JoinHostPort(proxy.Host, strconv.Itoa(proxy.Port)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("server: listen: %s", err)
    }
    log.Printf("server: listening on %s")
    proxy.listener = tls.NewListener(listener, &config)

    serverHTTPS := &http.Server{
        Handler:   proxy.mux,
        TLSConfig: &config,
    }

    if err := serverHTTPS.Serve(proxy.listener); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("SERVER ERROR:", err)
    }

   }
```

I tried a lot and generated several self-signed SSL-Certificates but nothing solved my problem.
Hope somebody can help me.

greetings

David

Comment: What is returning the certificate error? What is `httpProxy`? If apache is behind the go server, why is it https at all?

Comment: p.httpProxy = &httputil.ReverseProxy{
  Director: p.directorApache,
 }
Because if somebody connects directly to my apache.
And if I use the reverse Proxy as https and apache as http then I get erros about mixed content because of mixing https and http...

Comment: is it the proxy that's returning the cert error? Does apache have a cert signed by a trusted CA? You're setting `InsecureSkipVerify: true` on the listener, but that's a client setting (though you shouldn't need that at all with a valid cert).

Comment: I think the proxy returning the errorr as response form the Apache. I generated a self-signed cert for localhost with a tutorial, because i am new to SSL and those certificates.  How can i verify if its a valid cert or how can I get a valid cert? Oh ok thank you, i didn't know that.

Comment: I would advise against using apache directly and via reverse-proxy for the same project, as it only serves to complicate the architecture. If you need to connect directly to apache for some reason, connect to it for all resources it serves, or even put that in front of your go server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using a self-signed certificate in the backend server, you need to tell your proxy's http client to not verify the certificate.

You can override the default for the http package:

```
http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
```

Or create a new Transport specifically for your proxy:

```
httpProxy.Transport = &http.Transport{
    Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
    Dial: (&net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   30 * time.Second,
        KeepAlive: 30 * time.Second,
    }).Dial,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
}
```

Comment: thank you a lot. The first solution solved my problem very good :)